# How to create a hybrid gallery with Images & Videos?

Tags: image-galleries, channel-images, video

Trying to avoid using Matrix in this case but have an easily managed interface for the user.

Each will be a mini-gallery for a product page so would also prefer to avoid setting up a media channel and assigning media via a Playa field.

I like Channel Images - but not possible to chuck a video in the middle of all those images.... right?

What kinds of solutions have you used to combat the images/video hybrid gallery dilemma?

Comment: What video formats do you need to support?

Comment: Hi gomchild & welcome to the site. As currently phrased your question is too general/subjective to be a good fit for our Q&A format. [See this page of the FAQ](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) for more information about why this is, and consider rephrasing your question to be more specific and actionable.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Tom's comment on your question - more details and/or a rephrasing would be beneficial. However I'm going to provide an answer in any case.

I think the best way is to use Matrix as you can set two columns one for video and one for an image. All you need to is provide instructions that the client should choose either a video or an image but not both. You can then add other columns as needed for caption, title or whatever.

This really is the best solution for you and I'm not sure why you would want to avoid matrix in this case.

Answer (score 3):

*( follow-up on CreateSean's answer )*

If you don't want to use Matrix because you don't want to spend $55 for the license, you could always use this free alternative:

**Grid Lite**:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/grid-lite

> Grid allows you to dynamically add / delete and sort rows of data
>   similar to a spreadsheet. Each data row can have one or more cells
>   which are assigned to different custom fields (right now is only next
>   fields available: Text input, Textarea, Select box, Checkbox, Dates,
>   File. )